# Can you distinguish between the left CTRL key and right CTRL key using keycodes in .keypress()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

This code will fire an alert if I hit either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key:

```
$('#text').bind('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==17)
    {
        alert("Boo ya");
    }
});
```

Any way to only fire the alert if only the <kbd>left Ctrl</kbd> key is pressed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell if an event comes from right Ctrl key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590883/how-can-i-tell-if-an-event-comes-from-right-ctrl-key)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, at least using the keyCode. It'll be 17 for both keys. I don't know of any other method to distinguish between the two, and in my opinion, it's unlikely that there is one.

Answer (score 5):

I'm aware this question is quite old but nowadays it seems to be possible [KeyboardEvent.code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code):

```js
document.getElementById('i').addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  e.target.value = e.code;
});
```

```html
<input id="i" value="try keyboard here">
```

You should get `ShiftLeft` or `ShiftRight` by pressing either Shift key.

Comment: Any Idea, why on my Lenovo ThinkPad P53, I get "IntlRo" instead of "ControlRight" when pressing the right Ctrl Key, both on the builtin (german) keyboard as well as when I use an external (US-Layout) keyboard?