# How can I tell if an event comes from right Ctrl key?

Tags: javascript

I have an event listener in Javascript, I can tell whether a key event is Ctrl `(e.keyCode == 17)`, but how can I know this Ctrl comes from the right one or left one?

Comment: You can't. I'm sorry. I feel your pain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the keyCode is different.

You can use `e.ctrlKey` for a better way to determine if the control key was pressed.

It seems Flash [can not tell which one is pressed](http://www.artlebedev.com/everything/optimus/demo/) either (either that or coded incorrectly).

Comment: They are abstracted. E.g. I can choose a ton of different options for each of them in my Ubuntu Keyboard settings.

Comment: You can definitely write software that differentiates between the two on a low level, so no, it can't be abstracted on the hardware level. It's probably abstracted on the OS level, though.

Comment: MSIE can differentiate the left and right Ctrl key, see my answer on that point.

Answer (score 6):

Just a quick note: I wouldn't base an architecture / design on the availability of the right control key - many laptop keyboards may not have two control keys.

Answer (score 1):

MSIE provides a `ctrlLeft`property on most events. The property values are:

- `true` if the left key was pressed during the event
- `false` if the left key was not pressed.

You can combine `event.ctrlKey` and `event.ctrlLeft` to determine if the right Ctrl key was pressed:

```
if (event.ctrlKey) {
    if (event.ctrlLeft) {
        // left Ctrl key pressed
    } else {
        // right Ctrl key pressed
    }
} else {
    // no Ctrl key pressed
}
```

Note that the `ctrlLeft`property in a `keyup` is undefined because the Ctrl key is not pressed anymore.

Tested under MSIE7 and MSIE9. Does not work under Firefox.

See http://help.dottoro.com/ljqlvhuf.php for details.

Comment: Not very useful unfortunately if it's IE only.

Answer (score 1):

If you traced it you will find the same key is used for both (17) .. I think it is not possible to differentiate

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it was available when this was asked, but you *can* distinguish left- from right-ctrl, as well as alt and shift. You can now use the KeyboardEvent.DOM_KEY_LOCATION_* properties to make this distinction.

See [Can javascript tell the difference between left and right shift key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22029033/can-javascript-tell-the-difference-between-left-and-right-shift-key/22029109#22029109)

Be aware though, I discovered that Chrome appears to have a defect in its implementation. See [How can I distinguish left- and right- shift, ctrl, and alt keys onkeyup in Chrome with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22978448/how-can-i-distinguish-left-and-right-shift-ctrl-and-alt-keys-onkeyup-in-chro)

Answer (score 1):

There is `event.location` property for left ctrl key it will be 1 for right one 2, you can check browser support on [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-location)

```
if (e.which == 17) {
   if (event.location == 1) {
      // left ctrl key
   } else if (event.location == 2) {
      // right ctrl key
   }
}
```