# Detecting left and right control keys in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keydown, keyup

I have a text input, where I need to bind an event on doing a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>. I have set a global variable named `ctrl` which is set to 1 whenever a `keydown` is fired with a `which` value of 17. Similarly it is made 0 when a `keyup` is fired with `which` value of 17

Problem is, there are two <kbd>CTRL</kbd> keys. So if I do something like: first pressing the left <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key, and while pressing it down, press the right <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key also (so that both <kbd>CTRL</kbd> keys are pressed now), and then I release only one of them, the `keyup` is fired and the variable `ctrl` is set to 0, even though the other <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key is still being pressed.

How do I fire the events such that the variable is set to 0 only when both <kbd>CTRL</kbd> keys are up (I don't need to exactly differentiate between them).

Answer (score 3):

> Update : this is now possible in modern browsers

The easiest way to detect left and right control keys in Javascript

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("html").keydown(function(e) {

      if (e.ctrlKey) {
         if (event.location == 1) console.log('left ctrl');
         if (event.location == 2) console.log('right ctrl');
      }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note: You have to click the inside white space when you run code snippet to activate keyboard keys. This is tested in Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 2):

There are two properties for this of keydown event.
You can differentiate left and right Ctrl by using

```
if ( e.location == 1 || e.keyLocation == 1 ) {
    var keyPosition = 'left';
} else if ( e.location == 2 || e.keyLocation == 2 ) {
    var keyPosition = 'right';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way for that unless you write on lowlevel ... keyCode is the same for both (it is 17)

Just You can use e.ctrlKey as a way to determine if the control key was pressed.

However I read around and found [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14755036/1334561) mentioning you could do that in IE but I did not try it from my side

Answer (score 0):

you can use e.originalEvent.location instead of the global event.location

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("html").keydown(function(e) {

      if (e.ctrlKey) {
         if (e.originalEvent.location === 1) console.log('left ctrl');
         if (e.originalEvent.location === 2) console.log('right ctrl');
      }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

below is your answer for three mouse keyup events. rest for mousewheel you should ask again:

```
/*
 1 = Left   Mousebutton
 2 = Centre Mousebutton
 3 = Right  Mousebutton
*/

$(document).mousedown(function(e) { 
if (e.which === 3) {
    /* Right Mousebutton was clicked! */
    alert("right key code 3");
}
else if(e.which === 2) {
    alert("Centre key code 2");
}
else if(e.which === 1) {
    alert("Left key code 1");
}
});
```

Comment: Please read the question carefully, this is nowhere near to what I asked!

Answer (score -3):

you can use this:

```
$('#inputboxinput').bind('keypress', function(e) {
if(e.keyCode==13){
    // Enter pressed... do anything here...
}
```

});

the cross-browser way:

```
if (!event.which && ((event.charCode || event.charCode === 0) ? event.charCode: event.keyCode)) {
    event.which = event.charCode || event.keyCode;
}
```

Comment: Did you even read the question? Besides, jQuery already has `event.which` built-in. You don't need to re-invent it.

Comment: Umm, can you explain you answer in a bit more detail? I don't think that will work...