# How can I distinguish left- and right- shift, ctrl, and alt keys onkeyup in Chrome with Javascript

Tags: javascript, keyboard, dom-events, onkeydown, onkeyup

**UPDATE: This question is not a duplicate of another question. It does not have an answer elsewhere.**

I was inspired by this question [Can javascript tell the difference between left and right shift key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22029033/can-javascript-tell-the-difference-between-left-and-right-shift-key/22029109#22029109) to make a keyboard input class for a game kit, to distinguish key presses for individual keys.

The rub is that the `onkeydown` and `onkeyup` events in Javascript have identical keycodes for <kbd>left shift</kbd> or <kbd>right shift</kbd>, as well as <kbd>left ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>right ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>left alt</kbd>/<kbd>right alt</kbd>.

Per the response to the above question, modern browsers now return `event.location`, indicating whether these keys are left or right. IE and Firefox return the appropriate location value for these keys `onkeydown` and `onkeyup`.

But Chrome gives the correct value only `onkeydown`. In Chrome, <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, and <kbd>alt</kbd> all give a location `onkeyup` of `KeyboardEvent.DOM_KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD`, which is ambiguous.

Here is an example sandbox: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ySkn8/1/).

If you hit <kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, or <kbd>alt</kbd>, the `onkeydown location` will show correctly in Chrome (and all other browsers), but in Chrome the `onkeyup location` will be 'standard'.

relevant code:

```
window.onkeydown = function(event)
{
    var o = 'event = onkeydown, which = ' + event.which + ', location = ';
    
    switch(event.location)
    {
        case KeyboardEvent.DOM_KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD: o += 'standard'; break;
            
        case KeyboardEvent.DOM_KEY_LOCATION_NUMPAD: o += 'numpad'; break;

        case KeyboardEvent.DOM_KEY_LOCATION_LEFT: o += 'left'; break;
            
        case KeyboardEvent.DOM_KEY_LOCATION_RIGHT: o += 'right'; break;
    }
    
    var outputSpan = document.getElementById('output');
    
    outputSpan.innerHTML = o;
};

window.onkeyup = function(event)
{
    var o = 'event = onkeyup, which = ' + event.which + ', location = ';
    
    switch(event.location)
    {
        case KeyboardEvent.DOM_KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD: o += 'standard'; break;
            
        case KeyboardEvent.DOM_KEY_LOCATION_NUMPAD: o += 'numpad'; break;

        case KeyboardEvent.DOM_KEY_LOCATION_LEFT: o += 'left'; break;
            
        case KeyboardEvent.DOM_KEY_LOCATION_RIGHT: o += 'right'; break;
    }
    
    var outputSpan = document.getElementById('output');
    
    outputSpan.innerHTML = o;
};
```

Is this a bug, or somehow desired behavior? In light of this, is there another way to distinguish between the left and right side keys onkeyup?

UPDATE:

I worked around this by listening to which side the `keydown` came from, remembering it, and assuming that the subsequent `keyup` came from the same side. This isn't great, since it isn't necessarily true all the time.

This question is not a duplicate of [How can I tell if an event comes from right Ctrl key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590883/how-can-i-tell-if-an-event-comes-from-right-ctrl-key) which asked how to distinguish <kbd>left-ctrl</kbd> from <kbd>right-ctrl</kbd> key presses. That question is in fact answered by the question I originally referenced: [Can javascript tell the difference between left and right shift key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22029033/can-javascript-tell-the-difference-between-left-and-right-shift-key/22029109#22029109)

This appears to be a Chrome-specific defect in their API behavior, and since there isn't a full work-around, I might go file a bug report with the Chromium project.